# Ant / Jooq Generator - path to jooq libraries imported with maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, jooq

I have a multi-module `maven` project and I'm implementing an `ant` task to generate `jooq` classes directly from `jpa` entities.

These are tutorials I am referring to:

- [Code generation with Ant](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/code-generation/codegen-ant/)
- [Code generation from entities](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/codegen-jpa/)

My ant task that gives me errors is this one (I believe because the classpath is not set):

```
<target name="02-gen-jooq">
    <java   classname="org.jooq.util.GenerationTool"
            fork="true"
            failonerror="true"
            logerror="true">

        <arg value="/jooq-config.xml"/> <!-- my jooq config file in project root folder -->
        <classpath>
            <!--
            <pathelement location="?"/> // what to put here??
            <pathelement location="?"/>
            <pathelement location="?"/>
            -->
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

The error given is:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.jooq.util.GenerationTool

In the tutorial, the classpath is set as follows:

```
<pathelement location="/path/to/jooq-3.5.4.jar"/>
```

but it seems the libraries were manually imported. What should I put if the libraries are imported with `maven`?

Comment: Stupid question why do you use Ant when you have Maven?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I use Ant to create customizable build steps, and Maven just to download libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Ant standalone

You have to put all of these jar files on your ant classpath if you want to trigger the code generation outside of Maven:

- The JDBC driver
- jooq-{version}.jar
- jooq-meta-{version}.jar
- jooq-codegen-{version}.jar

See also:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration

#### Using Ant from Maven

The manual section you've linked shows how to use the maven-antrun-plugin:

```xml
<!-- Run the code generation task -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <java fork="true" 
                classname="org.jooq.util.GenerationTool"
                classpathref="maven.compile.classpath">
              <arg value="/path/to/configuration.xml"/>
          </java>
       </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <!-- JDBC driver -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
      <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The important line is:

```
classpathref="maven.compile.classpath"
```

This way, the Maven class path is passed to the ant process running the jOOQ code generator. If you put this plugin in a Maven profile, you can run it explicitly from the command line, without it affecting the Maven build lifecycle otherwise.

Of course, you're probably better off using the jooq-codegen-maven plugin as documented here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-maven

Comment: wouldn't this just generate `jooq` sources anytime I build?
My question's goal is to have a single ant `target` that I can click separately anytime I need to. Note that my knowledge on maven build is very limited though

Comment: You can use a Maven profile that you can invoke explicitly using `-P profile name`. If you specify the code generation output to be inside of a `/src/main/java` directory (rather than `/target`), then this will become completely independent of your Maven build lifecycle. It's really worth upgrading from ant to Maven, in general. I'll add some additional parts to the answer for ant-only configs, though.

Comment: for future readers, I have switched to maven, and one can only benefit from this